# Are 2FA TOTP scratch or recovery codes order-sensitive?

Tags: scala, security, playframework, silhouette, totp

I'm working on a [Google TOTP extension for Play-Silhouette](https://github.com/bravegag/play-silhouette/tree/googleauth), see  [the corresponding Play-Silhouette-Seed project here](https://github.com/bravegag/play-silhouette-seed/tree/googleauth) and was wondering whether the scratch or recovery codes are order-sensitive. By order-sensitive I mean that they must be used once and in the order given, sort of like the PIN/PUK/PUK2 cell phone unlock codes.

Another related question ... this is sort of obvious but better to be sure. Are scratch codes stored in a similar fashion as passwords? encrypted & salted too? I think it would make sense to treat them as passwords ... or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "scratch" codes are not a part of TOTP at all, it is just a mechanism to be used in case the TOTP profile is lost.
Therefore, there are no standards nor recommendations for these